# How do you get the screenOptions in a React Navigation screen component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I know I can do `setOptions` on the `navigation` object, but I can't seem to find the *get* version of it.  How do I obtain that information, namely I want to know if `headerLarge` is enabled.

What I have done as a workaround for now is have a `useEffect` on the header component that stores the screenOptions data into a context object keyed by route key.  With a return method that will remove it from the context when the header is unmounted.

Comment: "but I can't seem to find the get version of it" Can you explain what do you mean by this ?

Comment: I mean `getOptions()`

Answer (score -2):

You can set `headerLarge` using below code :

```
function MyStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Home"
        options={{
          headerLargeTitle: true,
        }}
        component={HomeScreen}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

PS : `headerLarge` is only for iOS.

Comment: Doesn't answer my question.  I am trying to get all the options though I am focused on one for my current situation.  Also headerLargeTitle is only available for nativestacknavigator not stack navigator.